# Android, Wifi reconnect not working

Tags: android, android-wifi

I have an Wifi router and I try to make connection like this:

```
WifiConfiguration wifiConfig = new WifiConfiguration();
wifiConfig.SSID = "\"" + wifiSSID + "\"";
wifiConfig.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN);
wifiConfig.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.WPA);
wifiConfig.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_PSK);
wifiConfig.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP);
wifiConfig.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP);
wifiConfig.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP40);
wifiConfig.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP104);
wifiConfig.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.CCMP);
wifiConfig.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.TKIP);
wifiConfig.preSharedKey = "\"" + wifiPassword + "\"";


WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);

int netId = wifiManager.addNetwork(wifiConfig);
Log.d("WIFI_RECONNECT", netId + "");
wifiManager.disconnect();
wifiManager.enableNetwork(netId, true);
boolean recon = wifiManager.reconnect();
Log.d("WIFI_RECONNECT", recon + "");
```

When I launch this code I receive this in my logs:

```
D/WIFI_RECONNECT: "My_WIFI_SSID" 1234567890
D/WIFI_RECONNECT: 67
D/WIFI_RECONNECT: true
```

However, my device shows that I have disconnected from all wifi routers that is accessible to me and my routers wifi network is shown in my available wifi list but not in connected mode.

Why this is happening?

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Thats happened cause `WifiManager.reconnect()` returns `true if the operation succeeded` and not when connection is completed. You should catch Wi-Fi state with Broadcast receiver after `reconnect()`